# How do you use drivers to hide an object or mesh?

Tags: drivers

instead of going into the outliner I would like to use the properties tab to change meshes.
I've tried to look for some tutorials but most of them are on shape keys.

For example; skin 1 is hidden and skin 2 is un-hidden when the value in the custom properties tab is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press Right mouse button over eye icon (or camera icon if you want to hide object in render) in outliner, chose Drivers > single from target.
2. mouse cursor will change to dropper, click on custom prop.
3. That is all!

[image]

Comment: wow, thank you for your help. I didn't realize it was that simple